# How to get Acceleration Time & Acceleration Magnitude in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, core-motion, motion, uiaccelerometer

Currently I'm trying to use CMAcceleration to get accelerometer values for x,y& z axis is it possible to get Acceleration Time & Acceleration Magnitude with this x,y & z values.When i checked the developer forum i can't find any delegates / methods to get this two.Guide me to find the values. 
Using the following code:

```
    int updatesensorFrequencyInterval = [sensorFrequencySliderTxt.text intValue];
self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = updatesensorFrequencyInterval;
self.motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = updatesensorFrequencyInterval;
[self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                         withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                             [self outputAccelertionData:accelerometerData.acceleration];
                                             if(error){
                                                 NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                             }
                                         }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x,y,z values of `CMAccelerometerData` acceleration struct are magnitudes in m/s^2.

`CMAccelerometerData` is a subclass of `CMLogItem`, so it inherits the `timestamp` property which provides the `NSTimeInterval` since the phone was booted.  This can be used to measure elapsed time between any pair of samples.

Comment: This time interval will return in Seconds ? Can you let me know how to get it as NanoSeconds.

Comment: Pretty sure this value is the same resolution as posix time.  Probably shouldn't trust fractional values less than 10ms.  I don't know where you would find nano resolution anywhere on the device.

Comment: Currently i'm using NSTimeInterval milisecondedDate = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000); for getting the microsecond value. Is it possible to get the value for getting the Gyroscope time interval.Please guide me in getting the values in Micro seconds as well as nano seconds.                                                 CMGyroHandler handler = ^(CMGyroData *data, NSError *error) {
            NSTimeInterval timestamp = data.timestamp;
            NSLog(@"timestamp->%f",timestamp);}

Comment: Should be fine.  But a good rule of thumb for time is to do all of your calculation and internal representation in the most native units, and only do scaling (e.g. *1k to milliseconds) and translating (e.g. +8hrs to PST) when you need to present time to the user.

Comment: Its not to the user, Just want to calculate.For internal purpose. Can you provide the code sample.

Comment: Just saying that there's no point in converting to ms or any other units for the sake of calculation or storage of these values.  You won't get any improvement over the native units (seconds since the epoch represented as double which is 64 bits).  In fact, you can only get non-improvement (the loss of precision) and -- more consequentially -- confusion in down-stream code over what units some value is in.  No code sample, just leave off anyplace where you multiply or divide by any power of ten.